# Endpoints of intervals of Cantor set survive construction

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, induction, cantor-set

While reading Rudin's proof that the Cantor set is Perfect, I realised that it assumes the endpoints of each interval survive the construction. I did not find this to be obvious to me. I tried proving it through induction, but I don't think that's allowed since there are infinite induction steps.

So how to prove that the endpoints survive construction?

The Cantor set $C$ construction being $$C_n = \frac{C_{n-1}}{3} \cup (\frac{2}{3} + \frac{C_{n-1}}{3})\;\;\; \text{ for $n \ge 1$, } \;\;C_0 = [0,1] $$ $$C:= \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} C_n$$
My attempt at a particular case (proving $0 \in C$):
$$\text{a) } 0 \in C_0$$
$$\text{b) For a particular } n \in \Bbb N , \text{ assume } 0 \in C_n$$
$$\implies0 \in C_{n+1} \text{ (as $\frac{0}{3} = 0)$ }$$
$$\therefore 0 \in C_n \;\forall\; n \in \Bbb N$$
But this does not prove that $0 \in C$ as $C$ is the intersection of infinite sets.

Comment: This *does* prove that $0\in C$. Recall what the intersection of all $C_n$'s *means*: it is the set of all elements that are contained in *all* $C_n$'s. And - you've proven that $0$ is contained in all $C_n$'s.

Comment: Note that the intersection of infinitely many open intervals may not be open

Comment: @StinkingBishop But I've just proven that $0$ is contained in all _finite_ $C_n$'s (atleast that is what I think). I'm not sure if this proof is enough to show that $0$ is contained in _all_ $C_n$'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show $0 \in C$ you exactly have to show $$\forall n: 0 \in C_n$$
because that's what the intersection *means*.
This fact can perfectly well be shown by induction on $n$ using the recursive/fractal nature of the $C_n$. So there is no problem at all with infinite intersections.

In fact all other endpoints (they have finite ternary expansion with only zeroes and twos, like $1$, $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{9}, \frac{2}{9} \frac{1}{27}, \ldots$ and countably many more) also all survive, and many others besides. These endpoints even form a countable dense set in $C$.

Comment: After your answer, this is what I'm inferring (please correct me if I'm wrong): I've proven that $0 \in C_n$ for all _finite_ n. The definition of arbitrary intersection says that if an element belongs to every _finite subcollection_ of sets in $\{C_n\}$, it belongs to the intersection of **all** sets in $\{C_n\}$. Is this true?

Comment: @edkav the definition of $C =!\bigcap_{n \in \Bbb N} C_n$ says that $x \in C$ iff $x \in C_n$ for all $ n \in \Bbb N$. So that’s what you have to show. Nothing about finite subsets etc. Note that the $C_n$ are nested/decreasing , so the collection of $C_n$ already has the fip (what we use to show non-emptiness of the intersection abstractly).